# USB Debugging Mode Not remembering PC

Tags: android, debugging, confirmation

[image: USB Debug]
Even if i tick "Always allow from this computer",each time i plug my android device i get this window on my device.
Any ideas what is the cause?

Comment: Now that you have the key fingerprint recorded in a screenshot, see if the one it shows next time is the same or different.  Perhaps you have an oddball device or a problem with your tools installation.  It would be helpful if you could try another PC or another device and see which the problem follows.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Do you use it on a physical machine or is it installed in a virtualization software?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My computer is windows 8.1,device is version 4.4.2 and it's a physical machine.@ChrisStratton Yes Chris it's the same key fingerprint and i don't have another pc at my disposal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem running cyanogenmod on my phone, if you are running a custom ROM just update the device.

Comment: I accepted your answer because i have 2 devices and this worked for the one with a custom ROM. But my other device it's the same problem ( without a custom ROM) .